# Debug test method in rails

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am finishing up Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and am stuck here https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-show_follow_view

Error in `test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb` caused by:

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
  @other_user = users(:archer)
end

test "should redirect following when not logged in" do
  get following_user_path(@user)
  assert_redirected_to login_url
end
```

Error message:

```
      1) Error:
    UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_following_when_not_logged_in:
    ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/users/762146111/following", :controller=>"users"}
      test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:62:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

The `@user` in the setup is pulled from `test/fixtures/users.yml`:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

`routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                    :following, :followers]

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end
end
```

`rake routes`:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
password_resets_new GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
   password_resets_edit GET    /password_resets/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
       sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
          users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
               root GET    /                                       static_pages#home
               help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
              about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
            contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
             signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
              login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                    POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
             logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
     following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format)          users#following
     followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format)          users#followers
              users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                    PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
                    GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
                    GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
                    GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                    GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                    PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
    password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
 new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
     password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                    PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
         microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)                   microposts#create
          micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)               microposts#destroy
      relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)                relationships#create
       relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)            relationships#destroy
```

I'm not sure why the error shows the route the test is attempting to hit as `/users/762146111/following`. 762146111 is where the user id should be which i assume should be 1. I have tried to do `rake db:migrate:reset` followed by `rake db:seed` but the id remains the same. I have also tried adding `debugger` into the method above the assertion but I am having trouble installing the `sudo gem install ruby-debug`. `byebug` also just runs through the tests without a breakpoint.

Any insight or ideas is greatly appreciated

Comment: A wild hunch - what would happen if you change `following_user_path(@user)` to `following_user_path(id: @user.id)` ? Or `following_user_path(@user.id)` ?

Comment: @IleEftimov hmm same error message for both of those

Comment: I'd be willing to test it out if you provide a repo with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set up the route to handle "users/:id/following"

You need this in your routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
```

Check out Listing 14.15 in the tutorial.

The weird number is what was used in test/fixtures/users.yml

Comment: i edited my question to include routes now. I had the mentioned routes and am still facing the problem. the rake routes looks like this: `following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format)          users#following`. So my routes are already nested and defined but the id just doesnt seem to be matching a user

Comment: That's not your problem. If you weren't matching a user you'd get a "record not found" error.  The "no route matches..." error indicates a routing problem.

Comment: do a `rake routes` command from the root of your application and post those results.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i included the routes as an edit to my question now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problema but in chapter 10 with the tests. In my case the problem was that i started the tutorial and generated the Users controller with an old version of Rails. The rails version got updated as I was going through the tutorial, so the Users controller belonged to the old version.

My solution was to destroy the Users controller, generate it again and write all the code that was erased all over again. Now it works perfectly.